# useHook return two elements in code definition and how to return one only when using in functional component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In my useHook function, I am returning two parameters.

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

export function useKeyAnnounce(

) {
  ....

  return [isPressed, setIsPressed];
}
```

when using in another functional component.

```
const [
    isPressedLocal,
    setIsPressedLocal
  ] = useKeyAnnounce();
```

say I only use `setIsPressed` and never use `isPressed`, how do I just return `setIsPressedLocal`?

Comment: I assume you mean, how do I change my usage of `useKeyAnnounce` to reflect that I only need one of the two return values, not "how do I rewrite `useKeyAnnounce` to only return one thing.

Comment: @Retsam, correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing *inherently* wrong with:

```js
const [
    isPressedLocal,
    setIsPressedLocal
] = useKeyAnnounce();
```

But many projects do consider it bad practice to have variables that are defined but not used.  (This is enforced by many linters, and sometimes the typescript compiler).  A common convention is that unused variables are prefixed by an underscore.  (You may need to configure your linter to allow this convention)  So I would write this as:

```js
const [
    _isPressedLocal,
    setIsPressedLocal
] = useKeyAnnounce();
```

You'll also see `_` itself used to denote an unused variable:

```js
const [_, setIsPressedLocal] = useKeyAnnounce();
```

or even just omitted with a leading comma:

```js
const [, setIsPressedLocal] = useKeyAnnounce();
```

But I think the version with the full name is clearer.

---

You could technically write this as

```js
const setIsPressedLocal = useKeyAnnounce()[1];
```

but I think this is pretty un-idiomatic.  (And the most annoying to refactor if you do eventually need `isPressedLocal`)

Answer (score 2):

> say I only use `setIsPressed` and never use `isPressed`, how do I just return `setIsPressedLocal`?

You should just reflect that you don't use it:

```
const [, setIsPressedLocal] = useKeyAnnounce();
```

But, you can just return a value depending on condition:

```
export function useKeyAnnounce({ isPressedUsed }) {
  ...
  return isPressedUsed ? [setIsPressed] : [isPressed, setIsPressed];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [ignore values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Ignoring_some_returned_values) when destructuring arrays by adding commas without variable names:

```
const [, setIsPressedLocal] = useKeyAnnounce();
```

This will skip index 0, and assign index 1 to `setIsPressedLocal`.

Example:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3]

const [,, v] = arr

console.log(v)
```